# Execute two statements using a WITH result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I need to execute two different statements based on the result of a WITH dataset. But the documentations says that a WITH can only be followed by a single instruction.

Is there a simple way to execute two statements using the dataset returned by that WITH ?. I was thinking of something like including my two statements within a begin ... end section, or parenthesis, ... ...

This is my code, I want to execute an UPDATE and an INSERT with the result of WITH :

```
  with EMPRESAS
  as (
    select splitdata as EMPRESA from fnSplitString(@EMPRESES_CONTA_SEPARADES_PER_COMA, ',')
    union
    select substring(@BRANCH_1,1,1)
  ), PROA_EMPRESAS
  as (
    select case EMPRESA when 'A' then 2 when 'B' then 5 when 'C' then 4 when 'D' then 1 when 'E' then 3 end as PROA_EMPRESA
    from EMPRESAS
  )

  update CLIENTE_CLIENTE_TIPO set CLG_COD = dbo.cCLIENTE_GRUPO_ClienteConActividad(), CCE_COD = @TARGMAG, CCT_ORI = 2
  from PROA_EMPRESAS
       inner join CLIENTE_CLIENTE_TIPO on CTI_COD = dbo.cCLIENTE_TIPO_Cliente() and CLI_COD = @CLI_COD and EMP_KEY = PROA_EMPRESA 
  where isnull(CLG_COD,-1) <> dbo.cCLIENTE_GRUPO_ClienteConActividad() or isnull(CCE_COD,'') <> @TARGMAG or isnull(CCT_ORI,-1) <> 2;

  insert into CLIENTE_CLIENTE_TIPO (CTI_COD, CLI_COD, EMP_KEY, CLG_COD, CCE_COD, CCT_ORI)
         select dbo.cCLIENTE_TIPO_Cliente(), @CLI_COD, PROA_EMPRESA, dbo.cCLIENTE_GRUPO_ClienteConActividad(), @TARGMAG, 2
         from PROA_EMPRESAS
              left outer join CLIENTE_CLIENTE_TIPO EXISTE on EXISTE.CTI_COD = dbo.cCLIENTE_TIPO_Cliente() and EXISTE.CLI_COD = @CLI_COD and EXISTE.EMP_KEY = PROA_EMPRESA
         where PROA_EMPRESA is not null and EXISTE.CLI_COD is null;
```

Is there a simple way to encompass my INSERT and UPDATE as a single instruction or do I really need to create an stored procedure or redefine my WITH for every instruction ?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities:

1) Use temp table to materialize intermediate resultset:

```
 with EMPRESAS
  as (
    select splitdata as EMPRESA from fnSplitString(@EMPRESES_CONTA_SEPARADES_PER_COMA, ',')
    union
    select substring(@BRANCH_1,1,1)
  )
    select case EMPRESA when 'A' then 2 when 'B' then 5 when 'C' then 4 when 'D' then 1 when 'E' then 3 end as PROA_EMPRESA
    INTO #temp
    from EMPRESAS;

update CLIENTE_CLIENTE_TIPO set CLG_COD = dbo.cCLIENTE_GRUPO_ClienteConActividad(), CCE_COD = @TARGMAG, CCT_ORI = 2
 from #temp PROA_EMPRESAS
 ...

INSERT INTO ...
select dbo.cCLIENTE_TIPO_Cliente(), @CLI_COD, PROA_EMPRESA, dbo.cCLIENTE_GRUPO_ClienteConActividad(), @TARGMAG, 2
from #temp PROA_EMPRESAS ...
```

2) Use `WITH` and `MERGE` statement:

```
with EMPRESAS
  as (
    select splitdata as EMPRESA from fnSplitString(@EMPRESES_CONTA_SEPARADES_PER_COMA, ',')
    union
    select substring(@BRANCH_1,1,1)
  ), PROA_EMPRESAS
  as (
    select case EMPRESA when 'A' then 2 when 'B' then 5 when 'C' then 4 when 'D' then 1 when 'E' then 3 end as PROA_EMPRESA
    from EMPRESAS
  )
  MERGE CLIENTE_CLIENTE_TIPO AS trg
  USING AS src
    ON src.... = trg....
  WHEN MATCHED AND add_condition... THEN
    UPDATE ...
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT
```

Comment: Very well explained. I'll take the first solution because it is the more straightforward to my current code. But at some point I'll need to learn to use MERGE. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The merge statement is perfect for this scenario. I tried to implement similar logic and it maybe wrong as it is a bit hard to visualize scenario without sample data and schema detail. you can refer MSDN documentation [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) AND [HERE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx)

Following is sample solution:

```
;WITH EMPRESAS AS 
(
    SELECT  splitdata as EMPRESA 
    FROM    fnSplitString(@EMPRESES_CONTA_SEPARADES_PER_COMA, ',')
    UNION
    SELECT  substring(@BRANCH_1,1,1)
), 
PROA_EMPRESAS AS 
(
    SELECT  CASE EMPRESA WHEN 'A' THEN 2 WHEN 'B' THEN 5 WHEN 'C' WHEN 4 when 'D' WHEN 1 when 'E' THEN 3 END AS PROA_EMPRESA
    FROM    EMPRESAS
)
MERGE   CLIENTE_CLIENTE_TIPO AS T
USING   PROA_EMPRESAS AS S
ON      CTI_COD = dbo.cCLIENTE_TIPO_Cliente() 
        AND CLI_COD = @CLI_COD 
        AND EMP_KEY = S.PROA_EMPRESA
WHEN    MATCHED
THEN    UPDATE 
        SET CLG_COD = dbo.cCLIENTE_GRUPO_ClienteConActividad()
        , CCE_COD = @TARGMAG
        , CCT_ORI = 2
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY T 
THEN    INSERT INTO CLIENTE_CLIENTE_TIPO (CTI_COD, CLI_COD, EMP_KEY, CLG_COD, CCE_COD, CCT_ORI)
        VALUES(@CLI_COD, S.PROA_EMPRESA, dbo.cCLIENTE_GRUPO_ClienteConActividad(), @TARGMAG, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have approved the other solution because he supplies two alternatives, but thanks a lot for taking the time to build a full proposal.